# Not able to get images from a link to imageview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uiimageview

In my Iphone app.i'm not getting the images in imageview.Those images are coming from a link.

link is http://pointngo.testshell.net/Images/2013-01-05%2001-05-59_20110623033304.jpg

i'm using this code.

```
UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:str]]];
```

Comment: what u get when u do NSLog("%@",str); ?

Comment: You have copy that from browser or from consol?

Comment: have try this both solution?

Comment: Try with Paras Joshi code @goutham...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :-

```
str = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:str]]];
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

try this code...

```
NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pointngo.testshell.net/Images/2013-01-05%2001-05-59_20110623033304.jpg"];

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];

UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

yourImageView.image = tmpImage;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure the `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:str]]` returns not `nil` . if `nil` you should use  `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`.

quote Apple Documentation : 
Return Value
A data object containing the data from the location specified by aURL. Returns nil if the data object could not be created.

Discussion
If you need to know what was the reason for failure, use `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following and it is working fine for me:

```
NSString *str = @"http://pointngo.testshell.net/Images/2013-01-05%2001-05-59_20110623033304.jpg";

//NSLog(@"Image data   %@", [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:str]]);

UIImageView *imgv = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50.0, 50.0, 100.0, 100.0)] autorelease];
imgv.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:str]]];
imgv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[self.view addSubview:imgv];
```